# How do I measure the overhead of a Postgres extended statistics object?

Tags: postgresql, statistics, database-size

Some solutions to poor query performance suggest creating [extended statistics objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createstatistics.html) to help the query planner better understand the shape of the data. Because these statistics objects are not created by default, I assume that they have some non-neglible overhead.

What kinds of overhead are present, what statistics object parameters factor in to the overhead, and can I quantitatively measure what the overhead of a specific statistics object is?

Some possible kinds of overhead I've thought of:

- Increased CPU usage

  - when inserting
  - when querying
  - when analyzing
- Increased memory usage
- Increased disk usage